# Wonderware Historian: query the Runtime.Events view

Tags: wonderware, historian

I'd like to query the Runtime.Events view with SQL. I have tried the followings:

`select * from Runtime.dbo.Events` gives the following error:

`OLE DB provider "INSQL" for linked server "INSQL" returned message "Event History no longer supports queries that do not provide time".`

`select * from Runtime.dbo.Events where EventTime >= '2018-09-01 00:00:00'  and EventTime <= '2018-11-01 00:00:00'` gives this not descriptive error:

`Cannot execute the query "..."  against OLE DB provider "INSQL" for linked server "INSQL".`

The date format seems to be right, because when I have tried with different format I got error referring to wrong date format.

How to query this view?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're trying to query for these events:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 *
FROM [A2ALMDB].[dbo].[v_EventHistory]
```

or these events:

```
SELECT * FROM Runtime.dbo.EventHistory
WHERE DateTime >= '2018-10-11'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to clarify this by a comment due to lack of reputation, so let me post an answer. May be your alarms and events are in A2ALMDB database. If that is the case, try the following query.

```
SELECT * FROM [A2ALMDB].[dbo].Events WHERE [EventStamp] between '2018-09-01 00:00:00' AND '2018-11-01 00:00:00'
```